# How to integrate Google Assistant and app shortcuts?

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, android-shortcut

I have seen that google assistant can call android app's shortcuts (Assistant >> Manage shortcuts to apps)

How can I add shortcuts to my app?
Can them be dynamic, I mean created by code?
Is there any limit in the number? I need about 10.
Do they have to be in the homscreen? I just need them to be called by Google Assistant.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no action on your end to set up Shortcuts. Google will gradually roll out this feature to more Apps. Find details [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171171059#comment3). Stay tuned for new related features to be released.